# memory order (consistency model) and C99

Tags: c, gcc, c99, c11, consistency

I see that C11 has additional features around memory_order (`<GCC_SOURCE>/gcc/ginclude/stdatomic.h`, 
[GCC Memory Model Wiki page](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/AtomicSync), [C11 Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) ).

I am curious to know what the default behavior is in C99 ? does it assume sequential consistency model by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Undefined.  Multi-threaded programming is outside the scope of earlier C standards.  If you're writing multi-threaded C99 programs you're relying on promises made by your compiler, not the C standard.

Answer (score 2):

The memory consistency models are defined for `_Atomic` data types and operations on them. This whole idea of atomics only was introduced in C11, so such memory ordering constraints simply don't apply.

The only pre-C11 feature that interacts with atomics are signals. C99 only had `sig_atomic_t` that let you communicate information between a signal handler and the rest of the program. Here the term "atomic" is to be understood in the primary sense, a data type that is guaranteed to be read or written in its entirety, not partially as it may happen with wider data types.

In C11, certain types of `_Atomic` data types are also guaranteed to behave well in signal handlers. So this is a case where you may be interested in `memory_order` even in the absence of threads.